# Numbering lines in textarea after enter

Tags: javascript, textarea, enter

I have a textarea and I want to numbering lines after enter key press. TextArea at once must display the number "1." and after all pressing enter add next numbers in new line, like "2. ", "3. ".

How to do that in javascript?